# Regex match tag with no spaces

Tags: regex

I've the below html tags.

```
<item id="ID1" num="num1">
<item id="ID1">
```

I want a regex to match `<item id="ID1">` and ignore `<item id="ID1" num="num1">`.

please let me know how can i do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
/<item id="[^"]+">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use \S+ to match any non-space characters.

```
<item id=\S+>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<item id=\"[^ ]*\">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/<item id=".*?"\s*>
```

You can try this.